# Time limit and wrong output in c

Tags: c

I am a beginner a C and I have made this code but it is giving infinite output. I want to take the average between two numbers.  The input of all the three range should be asked in beginning and output is displayed in new line.  Please help me to rectify the error.

This is the program made by me. Time limit is 3 seconds.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int avg(int,int);

int main()
{
  int i,t,f,s;
  int k[3];
  scanf("%d\n",&t);
  for(i=0;i<t;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d %d",&f,&s);
    k[i]=avg(f,s);
  }
  for(i=0;i=3;i++)
  {
    printf("%d",k[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}

int avg(int fst,int sst)
{
  int sum=0;
  int av;
  sum=fst+sst;
  av=sum/2.0;
  ///printf("%d",(int)ceil(av));
  return av;
}
```

And input/output should be like..

```
input:
3
1 10
1000 2000
200 350
output:
6
1500
375
```

Comment: `int av = sum/2.0;` will truncate the result, not round it. You need `av = round(sum/2.0);`.

Answer (score 0):

In your print loop, you have done

```
for(i=0;i=3;i++)    <------Problem in condition
{
 printf("%d",k[i]);
}
```

Instewad of `i=3`, you have to do `i<=3`. In every iteration you are assigning i=3.

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++)    <------Correct condition
{
 printf("%d",k[i]);
}
```

There are other problem also in your code.

1. What if t>3. You have initialized k array to 3. If t>3, there might be segmentation fault, if you are lucky.
2. In avg function, you have done `av=sum/2.0;` but av is of type `int` which will always provide you int value and truncate the decimal part.

Solution:

1. Either don't input `t` if you always want to input 3 pairs of number. Or else after input `t` do

   double *k = malloc(t*sizeof(double));

instead of `k[3];`

2. Change return type of the `avg()` function, type of `av` and array `k` to double.

Comment: How to correct segmentation fault..?? Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have used round function like this av = round(sum/2.0); now

Comment: You want the result to be integer? If you only want integer result then you can leave it like this.

Comment: double *k = new double(k);
This is giving compile time error

Comment: ok, sorry your is c code. Do `double *k = malloc (k*sizeof(double));`. I will edit my answer also.